# Prove almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory

> $\{X_n\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative r.v.s satisfying $EX_n=an^p$ for some $a,p>0$, and $Var(X_n)\le cn^r$ with $0<r<2p$ and positive constant $c$. Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{X_n}{n^p} = a$ a.s

Following is my attempt:
It's equivalent to prove $P(|X_n/n^p-a|>\epsilon \text{ i.o.})=0$
\begin{align}P(\cup_{n\ge m}|X_n/n^p-a|>\epsilon ) &=P(\cup_{n\ge m}|X_n-an^p|>\epsilon n^p ) \\
&= \dots \\
&= P(|X_m-am^p|>\epsilon m^p) \\
&= var(X_m)/\epsilon ^2 m^{2p} \\
&\le c/\epsilon ^2 m^{2p-r} \rightarrow  0
\end{align}
But I don't know how to fill the gap using the non-decreasing and non-negative.

Comment: What is a non-decreasing random variable? Would you actually assume  that the sequence $(X_n)$ is decreasing, meaning that $X_{n+1}\leqslant X_n$ almost surely, for every $n$?

Comment: I think it means $X_n \le X_{n+1}$ a.s. for every n

Comment: Yes, *non-decreasing*. Please modify your post.

Comment: @Did I didn't get your point

Comment: Wrong: "a sequence of non-decreasing and non-negative r.v.s" Correct: "a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative random variables".

Comment: @Did  Oh, I see. Thanks. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Sure. What do you know about the random variables $$Y_n=\frac{X_n-an^p}{n^p}\ ?$$